# How can I customize the coloring of the names of Python functions in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I've been trying to customize a color theme in VS Code and fiddled around with some properties a little bit. I found out that some properties are theme-dependant.

I've been sitting on attempting to customnize function calls as I found a theme that is nearly perfect but I am having trouble distingushing the calls from variables. I've tried something like this:

```json
//color customization
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Night Owl Black (No Italics)]": [
            {
                "textMateRules": {
                    "scope": "meta.function-call.Python",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#60c0e0",
                        // "fontStyle": ""
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
```

However, this doesn't seem to do anything. I also tried a different textmate token `meta.function-call.generic.python` with no luck

I've tried using semantic token highlighting but enabling them just turns syntax highlighting into a rainbow barf.

Comment: "_I've tried using semantic token highlighting but enabling them_" enabling what? semantic highlighting? You mean you didn't have it enabled when the token customization you were trying to make wasn't working?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to customize? Can you show us a minimal code sample and say explicitly what part of it you want to be coloured?

Comment: Semantic token highlighting wise:
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[theme]": {
        "enabled": true
    }
}
is not enabled by default, it's theme dependent, as far as VS code documentation goes, it uses Textmate for syntax highlighting method out of the box which is a different set of styling settings. 

As for the code, sample expression: 
os.scandir(path): - the scandir is a function (method?) call and is highlit in its own color - hence the "meta.function-call.Python" property as shown by "Dev> Inspect Editor Tokens and Scope

Comment: ahh, the formatting goes outta window in comments, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With semantic highlighting, you can do this (I'm just using the Monokai theme name for example purposes here. Replace it with whatever your theme's name is):

```json
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
   "[Monokai]": { // remove this wrapper to apply to all themes
      "rules": {
         "function:python": "#ff0000" // remove ":python" to apply to all languages
      }
   }
},
```

See also the `editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled` setting, the `enabled` property of `editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations` settings, and https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide.

---

With token colourization (and semantic highlighting enabled), the following two work pretty well (but not when semantic highlighting is disabled):

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
   "[Monokai]": { // remove this wrapper to apply to all themes
      "functions": "#FF0000",
   }
}
```

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
   "[Monokai]": { // remove this wrapper to apply to all themes
      "textMateRules": [
         {
            "scope": "entity.name.function", // applies to all languages
            "settings": {
               "foreground": "#FF0000",
            }
         },
      ]
   }
}
```

---

With semantic highlighting *disabled*, it seems trickier, having to write more scopes. I'm not sure if I've covered everything here:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
   "[Monokai]": { // remove this wrapper to apply to all themes
      "textMateRules": [
         {
            "scope": "meta.function-call.python, support.function.builtin.python", // remove ".python" to apply to all languages
            "settings": {
               "foreground": "#FF0000",
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Note that the above will also colour the parentheses and anything in them that don't have their own token colourization rules.

---

If you want to disable semantic highlighting for a particular language mode, you can do this:

```json
"[python]": {
   "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false
},
```

Comment: I have played around with your JSON snippets - the second to last one to be exact. I am not sure what I was doing wrong but it works! I've adjusted the scopes and achieved the goal of distinguishing member functions from built-in ones from user-defined ones. NOTES: The parenthesis and their contents do not get colored as they have their own tokens. Works way better than pure semantic tokens. I guess that Python has neatly defined tokens.

Answer (score 0):

If someone finds this obscure thread in the future - starball has provided some good config snippets. In my case the final solution was:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Night Owl Black]": { // <- replace with your theme
            "comments": "#91c4d5",
            "textMateRules": [
                { //imports and user-defined
                    "scope": "meta.function-call.generic.python",
                    "settings": {"foreground": "#f2d76b",}
                },
                /* { //Members
                    "scope": "meta.member.access.python, meta.function-call.python",
                    "settings": {"foreground": "#d6e830",}
                }, */
                { //built-in
                    "scope": "support.function.builtin.python, support.function.builtin.python",
                    "settings": {"foreground": "#ADDB67",}
                },
                {
                    "scope": "keyword.control.import.python",
                    "settings": {"foreground": "#2fccaf",}
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

This might help with customizing multiple properties too.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to modify the color when calling a function, you can use the following settings:

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "meta.function-call",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#60c0e0"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Sadly that still doesn't affect the theme.