# Restoring VS-code variable colors for python after installing C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, settings

I am having troubles with seeing variables in color in my VS-code. My VS-code was working fine showing the python code with the variables in a blue color. I got the "Microsoft C++ Build Tools" installed since that time the variables are now mostly just white. What I tried is...

1. uninstall and reinstall the python extension.
2. uninstall the extensions of C++ intelliSencse, C++ Extension Pack, C++ Themes.
3. Reset the settings.json file.
4. Close and reopen VS-code
5. Changing the chosen color theme use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+K Ctrl+T.
6. specifying the variable color in settings.json file see code below.

```
{
    "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,

    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "variables": "#0026ff"
    },
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    
}
```

After doing all of this I am not getting expected blue color for the variables. What do I do to fix this?

[image]

[image]

References:

- [how to change the color of variables in VScode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63357054/how-to-change-the-color-of-variables-in-vscode)
- [make-vscode-variables-have-colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47724696/make-vscode-variables-have-colour)

Comment: FYI: I am using Windows.

Comment: this might be a semantic highlighting thing. see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/76878302/11107541. What if you disable semantic highlighting in the settings? What do you see if you inspect the token colours and scopes? (use the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` command in the command palette). more examples of things related to semantic highlighting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76575657/11107541

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found is to change from Pylance extension of v2023.9.20 back to an older version of v2023.9.10.

The installation of C++ was just coincidental.